# A word to describe a player's possible action during their turn

Tags: single-word-requests

Given an ongoing game with well defined rules, a player and granted that it is their turn, how would you call the possible actions the player can perform?

These actions may include moving a piece, rolling dice, trading with another player, resigning, etc. Anything that advances the game in any way, no matter how reasonable. In particular, I would like to refer to **all actions the player is able to perform**, i.e. usually a huge amount.

My first thought was along the lines of *actions* or *game actions*, though I would like to avoid that term if possible. *Decisions* would be quite detached from a *performed* action.

Update: Trying to add examples

> There are 5 possible actions that can be carried out by player 1.
>
> - Moving piece X from field A to field B, claiming field B
> - Moving piece Y from field C to field D, capturing the enemy piece Z
> - Buying card foo from the bank, reducing 1's tokens to 4, gaining privilege bar
> - Moving piece Y from field C to 1's inventory, losing field C to player 2
> - Resigning the game, moving pieces X and Y to 1's inventory, losing field A to player 3 and field C to player 2.

The distinction am I looking as seen in the final example: Resigning the game does *cause* them to lose all their stuff, but the important part is not the reasoning but what actually *happens* when they chose this action. For this reason the carried out action and all direct subsequent consequences are bundled together.

In chess, an example might be:

> - Move white queen to A7, remove black bishop from A7 and add black bishop to black graveyard
> - Move white pawn from E2 to A4, define black the winner of the game, game ends (this one is a bit far fetched)

Comment: Define a term, then use it.  This would be part of the jargon for using the game.  Without knowing the game, it is hard to tell what sort of term would best fit.  I have seen "actions", "impulses", "rounds", "activations" used for this...

Comment: @Oldcat Good idea, but I was hoping for a very generic term, if it exists. Or, well, to follow through, we might call it a _papp_ (possible action performable by player) :)

Comment: I can't quite visualize what you're looking for. Could you please add an example of the context for this word (ie., a sample sentence) and explain why you're avoiding *action*? Because that seems like the usual game jargon.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I edited the question, no sure if that clears it up really. -- I would like to avoid _action_ because it leads to naming collisions in my particular case.

Comment: Are you looking for a word to replace *actions* in "5 possible actions"? If so, then I think *actions* is really the best term, used in many similar games. If not, please write an example sentence that demonstrates both what you want to write and why *actions* doesn't work.

Comment: How about simple calling them _moves_? The word is already used quite loosely in various forms of games (“Your move!” works fine even if you’re playing tic-tac-toe where no movement is involved, for example). I’d say a _move_ is simply anything and whatever you do to change it from being your turn to it being the other guy’s turn.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Yes to your question. -- I also think that _actions_ would probably be easiest, I'm just looking for alternatives, since the term is already used for something different in my case that I'm unable to change (not important in this question).

Comment: In that case I'd go with move or play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> These actions may include moving a piece, rolling dice, trading with another player, resigning, etc. Anything that advances the game in any way, no matter how reasonable. In particular, I would like to refer to all actions the player is able to perform, i.e. usually a huge amount.

The best word to cover all the actions described is "move". It's a fairly neutral word that describes pretty well anything the player does, which might be a tactical manoeuvre, or it might be nothing more than a standard bit of business with no particular significance. If you want to denote something that tends towards a tactical manoeuvre, it might be "ploy" or "stratagem" or "gambit".

Comment: +1. You beat me to it by exactly three seconds (though I only posted mine as a comment)!

Answer (score 4):

You can consider using *options*.

Answer (score 2):

Why not **[activity](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/activity)**

> any specific deed, action, pursuit, etc.

You also might consider **[play](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/play)**

> (US & Canadian) a move or manoeuvre in a game: *a brilliant play*

Comment: I think _play_ captures it very well, doesn't it? - it is an option that is (or can be) performed

Comment: +1 for *play.* Some games also use *move* for this.